# seminar about the strong multiplicity one for the Selberg class

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, l-functions, selberg-class

Very recently, a seminar took place in Seoul with Haseo Ki as an invited speaker to talk about the strong multiplicity one theorem for the whole Selberg class that he did manage to prove. I would like to know if he gave explicit consequences of such a result, like, say, whether it implies that a positive proportion of elements of the considered class satisfies the degree conjecture, and perhaps progress towards establishing the unique factorization conjecture.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably it would be more efficient to just ask Ki?

Comment: And it would have been even more efficient to attend the seminar...which may be the case of some members of this site, hence my question.

Comment: Is his proof (paper) available? If yes, where?

Comment: There: web.yonsei.ac.kr/haseo/smo.pdf